# Specifying font-size in relative units in particular style sheet

Tags: html, css, fonts, responsive-design

I want set font-size in relative units (em) in Drupal [responsive](http://demo.zymphonies.com/free-theme/software-responsive-theme/index/) theme's [CSS style sheet](http://demo.zymphonies.com/free-theme/software-responsive-theme/index/sites/all/themes/software/css/stylee683.css).
I know, it's best to use relative font size units: in my case its relative to `body font-size` (13px): but I'm not sure, does this value must be left in **px** absolute units? If I specify **body font-size** in relative unit (**em**), then 
I can no use **em** relative units for all of the *other elements*, as setting unit that is *relative to relative unit* make no sense. What is proper way to specify font-size in this particular stylesheet?
The CSS (part related to question) looks as follows:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
...
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 160%;
  color: #666;
  font-size:13px;
  background: #fff;
}
....
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom:6px;
  color: #555;
}

h1 {  font-size:18px; }

h2 {  font-size:16px; }

h3 {  font-size:14px; }

h4 {  font-size:13px; }

h5 {  font-size:13px; }

h6 { font-size:13px; }

p {  margin-bottom:18px;
    color: #666;
}
...
#forum .name a{ 
  font-size: 16px;
}
....
```

Comment: You are asking about modifying a particular style sheet, but the question does not include it. Questions where an essential part of the problem description is available only via an external link are not suitable for SO. Besides, what *is* the question? Asking for “proper way” is very vague (and opinion-oriented). And setting a unit as relative to a relative unit makes a lot of sense, so the key assumption is wrong.

Comment: I want set the font size in **em** units. So I should left body font-size in pixel unit and for all of the other elements set font values in em. If I set body font-size also in em, this probably will not give me any advantages. How to convert pixel units to em, while preserving the aspect ratio/proportions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It all depends on what are you trying to achieve.** It's nothing wrong with using absolute units like pixels **(px)** or points **(pt)**. Just like you wrote. If you want all of your styles depends on the body font-size, you should probably use em. This way, by changing the body font-size it will affect other elements, which is great, because you don't have to edit all of the styles. It will be more efficient and speed up your work.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/su4tzvn9/

```
body {
    font-size:13px;
}

h1 {
    font-size:2em;
}

p {
    font-size:1.2em;
}
```

Comment: I have no issues with existing stylesheet, just want to improve CSS a bit, to make it slightly better, by following the recommended approach of use relative units for the font size.

Comment: The pixel, is used if you want absolute control or in case you need a "pixel perfect" result. With the em unit, the font size is relative to the container font size, while with the rem unit the font size is relative to the root element font size. The relative units, are usually used if the font size needs to change according to the screen size. It provides easier manipulation and less media queries usages. For example: 
html {font-size: 16px}
div{ font-size: 1rem } //this equals to 16px.

There is a great article you can read here https://kolosek.com/css-relative-font-size/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base font size in pixels, and for further elements, use percent. Hence, every child of `body` will have a font-size in percent of what's specified for `body`. So, if you have a html and css like this:
`

```
body
{
 font-size:10px;
}
body div:first-child
{
 font-size:110%;
}
body div:last-child
{
 font-size:150%;
}
<body>
  <div>Sample text1</div>
  <div>Sample text2</div>
</body>
```

then `sample text1` will have a font-size of 11px while `sample text2` will have font-size of 15px. In case of responsive designs, you can change the font size (in percent) for each of these `divs` or even for body (lets say, for mobile you set body font to 12px and for higher resolutions, you set it to 14px), then your text will be resized accordingly on different devices!